# Distance from point to a line wrong answer help!

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

I don't know what I did wrong please check. The correct answer is at the bottom of the picture. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't know what I did wrong please check. The correct answer is at
>   the bottom of the picture. Thanks.

$PP_0 • d = 1$ not $-1$. So your $\vec{PQ}$ should be $\frac{1}{\sqrt{14}}×\vec{(1,2,-3)}$

Comment: Ahh I see. I plugged in the wrong values